# Xcode 4.6 IPhone/IPad Copy Field, using setText "Incompatible pointer types"

Tags: iphone, ipad, pointers, xcode4.6

I am trying making a simple iphone app that copies text from one field to another when you press a button (text1 values into text2), but I am getting my some warnings "Attributes on method implementation and its declaration must match" and "Incompatible pointer types sending 'UITextField *' to parameter of type 'NSString *". Both text1 and 2 and declared as UITextField. The warnings are in the setText line.

```
#import "APPViewController.h"

@interface APPViewController ()

@end

@implementation APPViewController

-(IBAction)copy:(id)sender
{
     [text2 setText:text1];
}


@end
```

Comment: Just use `text2.text = text1.text;` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text1` is a `UITextField *`, not an `NSString *`.  You need to ask `text1` for its contents by sending it the `text` message.

```
[text2 setText:[text1 text]];
```

You can also use “dot notation”, like this:

```
text2.text = text1.text;
```

The second form compiles into exactly the same executable code as the first form.

Comment: That fixed it thanks! I'm still getting the warning "Attributes on method implementation and its declaration must match". I seem to be calling it correctly though. The call is "-(IBAction)copy:(id)sender;"